# Sum in html template using template tag

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-template-filters

I am trying to sum in HTML,but template tag return 0 ,

View.py

```
def gen_Report(request):

### query returns below output 
list=[{'total': 1744, 'user': u'x'}, {'total': 13, 'user': u'y'}, {'total': 126, 'user': u'z'}, {'total': 46, 'user': u'm'}, {'total': 4, 'user': u'n'}, {'total': 8, 'user': u'o'},  {'total': 3, 'user': u'p'}]

return render_to_response('user.html', locals(),
                            context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

Template :

```
user.html

  {% load temptags %}

 <table id="myTable" class="tablesorter">
    <thead>
    <tr>

    <th>S.No</th>
    <th>role</th>
    <th>Count</th>

    </tr>
    </thead>
    {% for fetch in list %}

    <tr>
    <td>{{forloop.counter}}</td>
    <td>{{fetch.user}}</td>
    <td>{{fetch.total}}</td>



    {% endfor %}
    <td>{{ list.total|running_total}}</td>
    <tr>

    </table>
```

Template tag:

```
from django.template import Library
register = Library()
@register.filter
def running_total(list_total):
  return sum(d.get('list_sum') for d in list_total)
```

output :

```
S.No    user          Count
1     x       1744
2     y         13
3     z         126
4     m         46
5     n              4
6     o          8
Sum------------------>   0  (it returns zero)
```

I am doing anything wrong here ?

can you please help me,how to return sum total using template tag here ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your template tag looks wrong.  You have `role_total` as the parameter and then iterate through `list_total` (seemingly undefined) and from each dictionary in the list try getting the key `list_sum` which is also seemingly undefined.

```
from django.template import Library
register = Library()
@register.filter
def running_total(your_dict_list):
   return sum(d['total'] for d in your_dict_list)
```

and calling it from the template at as `<td>{{ list|running_total}}</td>`

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that your list is an iterator. So the first time it iterates over and the second time it iterate over nothing.
So you should do something like this

```
for d in list_total:
   d.set('list_sum', list(d.get('list_sum')))
```

before calling your template

Comment: i need to add in view or template tag?