# Get sum of values in the loop

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I have a cycle in the template:

```
{% for article in user.article_set.all %}
    {{ article.article_date }}
    {{ article.article_title }}
    {{ article.article_cost }}
{% endfor %}
```

How can I show the sum of all `{{ article.article_cost }}` in that cycle (not count)? Or I need to write something in my view?

I tried that, but I don't know, how to use it in my template, so I don't know, is that work or not:

```
u = User.objects.get(username=username)
total_price = u.article_set.all().annotate(total=Sum('article_cost'))
```

Full view:

```
def userprofile(request, username):
    u = User.objects.get(username=username)
    total_price = u.article_set.all().annotate(total=Sum('article_cost'))
    if request.POST:
        user_form = UserForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        user_profile = UserProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.profile)
        if user_form.is_valid():
            user_form.save()
        if user_profile.is_valid():
            user_profile.save()
    else:
        user_form = UserForm(instance=request.user,
            initial={
                'first_name': request.user.first_name,
                'last_name': request.user.last_name,
                'email': request.user.email,
            })
        user = request.user
        profile = user.profile
        user_profile = UserProfileForm(instance=profile)

    return render_to_response('profile.html', {'user_form': user_form, 'user_profile': user_profile}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django sum of row in template for loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21404051/django-sum-of-row-in-template-for-loop)

Answer (score 2):

I would definitely recommend that you calculate the sum in your view, and then pass it in as context to your template. Have a look at [this link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/api/), it will give you a better understanding of templates and template context.

Comment: But can you tell me, what I'm doing wrong? I want to extract `article_cost` and `sum` it with `total_price = User.objects.all().article_set.all().annotate(total=Sum('article_cost'))` but got `'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'article_set'`... But in template `user.article_set.all` is working well...

Comment: `article_set` is Related Manager, thus it can only be called on a model instance, in this case an instance of the `User` model. `User.objects.all()` returns a queryset and that is the error you are seeing.