# access multiple many to many relationships in a django template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

```
class Account(models.Model):
    accountId = models.CharField(max_length=20, primary_key=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

```
class Project(models.Model):
    projectId = models.CharField(max_length=20, primary_key=True, default=idgen)
    projectName = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    projectOwner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="owner")
    projectSize = models.IntegerField(default=25)
    projectGuests = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="guests")
    projectAccounts = models.ManyToManyField(Account, "accounts")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.projectId
```

In this code, users can have multiple projects and projects can have multiple accounts. Is there any way to pass just the 'user' to the template (or without passing anything since we can get the user using the request) to get all the accounts in all the projects that the user owns without using a for loop? cause I have to display a count of accounts in total that the user owns.

for example, if the user had 2 projects and each project had 2 accounts... is there any way to get the final value 4 in the template just using the user object?

Answer (score 1):

Try this Query

```py
accounts = Project.objects.filter(projectOwner=request.user).projectAccounts_set.all()
```

Comment: Thank you. but is there any way to do this inside the template other than views.py?

Comment: why do you want to do in inside the template?

Comment: Just seeing if it's possible.

Comment: you cannot write the ORM inside the template.

Comment: I see. 
```
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'projectAccounts_set'
 ```
got this error.

Comment: try this
`accounts = Account.objects.filter(projectOwner__projectOwner=request.user).all()`

Comment: didn't work. it's fine. I did it in views.

Answer (score 1):

It is best to perform such arithmetic in Django views rather than templates [21404051](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21404510/11943384).

First select all Projects related to `request.user` by

```
projects = Project.objects.filter(projectOwner=request.user)
                  .annotate(pc = Count('projectAccounts'))
                  .aggregate(total = Sum('pc'))
```

Now in template

```
{{ projects.total }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I decided to do it in views.py after all since it looks impossible to do in templates.

```
accs = []
for project in request.user.owner.all():
    for account in project.projectAccounts.all():
        accs.append(account)
accs = list( dict.fromkeys(accs))
```

this was a simple solution. pretty sure there are way easier and more efficient ways to do this.