# Trying to get sum of values in a for loop but filter is returning 0 - Django

Tags: python, django

I am just trying to get a "Thanks" count for my user based on the thanked field in this Advice model:

```
class Advice(models.Model):
    user            = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, blank=True)
    content         = models.TextField()
    slug            = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    thanked         = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, related_name='adviceliked')
    question        = models.ForeignKey(Question, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1, related_name='advices')
```

In my views I have tried

```
thanks_count = Advice.objects.filter(user__username=requested_user) \
        .aggregate(total_thanks = Sum('thanked'))
```

and it works for the first "thank" but then every one after that the count gets infinitely larger.

So then I tried it with annotate:

```
thanks_count = Advice.objects.filter(user__username=requested_user).annotate(
            total=Count('thanked')
            )
```

and in my template:

```
{% for advice in thanks_count %}
    {{ advice.total }}
{% endfor %}
```

This gets the correct "thank" count for each advice, but I need the sum of all the thanks, not just a list of "thank" counts for each advice.

So then I tried this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/5275944 to total the counts of every item in the for loop. I created the filter:

```
@register.filter
def total_thanks(thanks_count):
    a = sum(advice['thanked'] for advice in thanks_count) 
    return a
```

and in my template:

```
{{ advice|total_thanks }}
```

but it is only returning a sum of "0".

I'm pretty sure the error is with the template tag, but when I use {{ thanks_count|total_thanks }}, it returns "'Advice' object is not subscriptable"

Sorry if this is confusing, I will try to clarify if anyone needs me too. Any help or points in the correct direction would help a bunch. I have spent way too long trying to figure out this seemingly simple problem.

Thank you very much!!!!

Comment: in place of ['thanked']? or a = sum[(advice['thanked'] for advice in thanks_count)]?

Comment: Do you mean to have the ) before the closing ]

Comment: The answer below resolved it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have the total `thanked` for each advice, the easiest way would be to just sum them up:

```
total_thanks_count = sum(Advice.objects.filter(user__username=requested_user).annotate(total=Count('thanked')).values_list('total', flat=True))
```

Hope it helps!